# What do you call an actor's lines in a movie as a whole?

Tags: word-request

What do you call an actor's lines in a movie as a whole? Because a script involves more than lines (and for more than just one actor). I'm not sure whether 'role' and 'part' work.

Comment: "Dialogues" probably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've actually used the word I would probably pick as a native speaker, and which seems to be common:

> Has the actor learnt his **lines** yet?

**Part** would work more generally if you meant more than just the words they are to say.